# Finding a general solution of a partial differential equation.

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Let $p= \frac{\partial z}{\partial x}, ~q= \frac{\partial z}{\partial y}$.  Find the general solution of the partial differential equation $z = p x+ qy +p+q -pq$, by finding the envelope of those planes that pass through the origin. It is given that, $z =ax+ by + a+b -ab$ is a complete integral.  (This question is part of a problem from the book "Elements of partial differential equations" by Ian N. Sneddon.)

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

$z=x\dfrac{\partial z}{\partial x}+y\dfrac{\partial z}{\partial y}+\dfrac{\partial z}{\partial x}+\dfrac{\partial z}{\partial y}-\dfrac{\partial z}{\partial x}\dfrac{\partial z}{\partial y}$

$z=(x+1)\dfrac{\partial z}{\partial x}+(y+1)\dfrac{\partial z}{\partial y}-\dfrac{\partial z}{\partial x}\dfrac{\partial z}{\partial y}$

Let $\begin{cases}r=x+1\\s=y+1\end{cases}$ ,

Then $z=r\dfrac{\partial z}{\partial r}+s\dfrac{\partial z}{\partial s}-\dfrac{\partial z}{\partial r}\dfrac{\partial z}{\partial s}$

Answer (score 0):

The planes $z=ax+by+a+b-ab$ pass through the origin if $a$ and $b$ satisfy the relation
$$
a+b-ab=0 \implies b=\frac{a}{a-1}. \tag{1}
$$
Substituting $(1)$ in the equation of the planes we find
$$
z=ax+\frac{ay}{a-1}. \tag{2}
$$
The envelope of these planes is obtained by eliminating $a$ between $(2)$ and the equation
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial a}\left(-z+ax+\frac{ay}{a-1}\right)=0 \implies x+\frac{y}{a-1}-\frac{ay}{(a-1)^2}=0. \tag{3}
$$
Solving $(3)$ for $a$ we obtain
$$
a=1\pm\sqrt{\frac{y}{x}}. \tag{4}
$$
Substituting $(4)$ in $(2)$ we finally obtain
$$
z=\left(\sqrt{x}\pm\sqrt{y}\right)^2, \quad \text{or} \quad (z-x-y)^2=4xy. \tag{5}
$$